# Form submit prevent not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I got a meany on my hands.
I often use regular buttons instead of submit type buttons to have a bit more control over my forms. In this case I am trying to submit a form that is not present on the initial load, but is rather imported if the user makes the choices that lead to that.

To keep things simple I have added the .on("submit") to the same scope as where I trigger the submit, just to prevent jquery from getting confused.

```
        var form = $('form#create_topics');
        form.submit();
        form.submit(function(e) {  
            console.log("test");
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
```

The submitting works, the preventing default processing does not.
Not I have already tried .on("submit", function(e) and I have already tried form.submit(); after binding the .submit :)

I am guessing the reason its not working is due to my specific situation, any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you bind handler BEFORE trigger the submit() event? I'm not sure to understand why you need/want to trigger submit event here. You'd have better to provide a jsFiddle, maybe?! BTW, you could delegate submit event, could be what you are looking for instead

Comment: Well, for one thing, the quoted code has a syntax error...

Comment: tried  triggingering the submit after, no avail :)  a jsFiddle for the situation where a form is imported is a bit much work, but in worst case should this not be enough I can always bother with it :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I must be really not awake (Im ill at the moment:)) where do you see a syntax error? :)

Comment: give a fiddle so that we can figure out your specific issue

Comment: @Pwnball: You never close the second call to `submit`. You're missing the `);` at the end of your code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var form = $('form#create_topics');
form.on("submit",function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    if(condition matches){
        form.submit();
    }
});
```